# Is my Processor 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

Not to be confused with [Is my OS 32-bit or 64-bit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127322/is-my-os-32-bit-or-64-bit).

This one is very simple, tell me whether or not my CPU supports 64-bit instructions. If my CPU supports 32-bit instructions, print '32', if my CPU supports 64 bit instructions, print '64', if my processor *naitively* supports other lengths of instructions, print 'other'.

Your program must run on both 32 and 64-bit instruction modes, and if interpreted run properly on both 32 and 64-bit interpreters.

Test cases:

Arch: x86, i386, i686, RiscV32
Output: '32'

Arch: x86-64, x64, x86_64, RiscV64
Output: '3264'

Arch: R700
Output '32other'

The usual [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

Best of luck!

Comment: I don't think this should be tagged as a `decision-problem`, since there are more than 2 possible answers. (Although both the title and the 1st sentence of the description suggest that it's a "yes/no" kind of problem.)

Comment: @Arnauld A decision between more than 2 options is still a decision.

Comment: Sure, but it's not a [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/decision-problem/info) anymore [as defined in computability theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem).

Comment: Is that the full list of inputs we're expected to handle and is there any flexibility in the output?

Comment: I don't think any of the existing answers ever print `other`, maybe you should consider removing that requirement.

Comment: To clarify, it needs to print 3264 even if compiled as 32-bit code and run on a 32-bit operating system on a processor that also supports 64-bit mode?

Comment: @user253751 yes

Comment: @Arnauld Ah, then it is 3 decision problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, <s>33</s> 25 bytes

```bash
lscpu|grep -Po '..(?=-b)'
```

[Don't try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P6c4uaC0Jr0otUBBNyBfQV1PT8PeVjdJU/3/fwA) Won't work because the TIO sandbox doesn't support lscpu. Edit: Saved 8 bytes thanks to @DigitalTrauma.

Comment: it even works on RISC-V Debian!

Comment: That's Linux specific, isn't? `lscpu` isn't present on all OSses, not even all Unices.

Comment: @Abigail I'd still say it's legal, as it's interpreted, and it runs properly for 32 or 64 bit linux

Comment: @tuskiomi I'm pretty sure what Abigail meant was that the title of the post isn't correct. I'd guess it should say something like Bash + coreutils on Linux, at the very least. I'm not sure if there's a better name or way to identify what contains this command.

Comment: Use grep's PCRE flag to obviate the need for sed: `lscpu|grep -Po '..(?=-bit)'`

Comment: Also, `-b` seems to be sufficient instead of `-bit' - at least on my system.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 45 bytes

```
||if std::usize::MAX>4294967295{3264}else{32}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY3BCgIhFEX3fsVrVgq1cWxCC6GNu2jbNupJwiShDkGO3266u2dxzwlLTNV6eN@dpwwyAUgYE63r6izE9FRqie6HSl3ONy24FHI6cLnPI59EwTliW6UCsCMphDRTv5@MplaBYeT7woBNahr5q39gi@w0uJGT3gL4BOfT7Dd0yGXYgqWsm@of) (Cross compile for 32-bit locally by installing a toolchain for i686. For example: `stable-i686-pc-windows-msvc`)

Can't really test this on any architectures that support "other" lengths of instructions, but this can be used to check for 32-bit or 64-bit architectures. This is shorter than the built-in way using `cfg!(target_pointer_width="64")`.

Comment: Does not work. This is 3264 when compiled as 32-bit on a 64-bit processor.

Comment: @user253751 Can you share what steps you took to compile for 32-bit? The documentation for usize states that [the actual size of usize is based on the pointer size](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html). It was working for me fine when I targeted i686, but I'm not completely sure how to target 32-bit aside from that.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say the *correct* output would be 3264 and this outputs 32. I did not run it, but it is obvious by inspection...

Comment: @tuskiomi Can you clarify what should happen if your code is cross-compiled? Currently my solution works if you target the architecture you're on, but assumes the target architecture if you cross-compile.

Comment: it seemed pretty clear to me. "If my CPU supports 64 bit instructions". **NOT** "If the program contains 64 bit instructions"

Comment: If it's clear, let the question asker clarify. My code runs on both 32-bit and 64-bit instruction modes like the question asked. It wasn't clear whether the code should still output 3264 after being compiled in a non-standard way on 64-bit architecture.